# Trying to use pygame event function to allow player to exit game if x is pressed

Tags: python, pygame

If you look at the below code, I have if conditions inside my drawing function to present a winner screen and loser screen based on the length of the target sprite group (this is a target shooter game). I have added a boolean variable called game_over. When the loser or winner screen is shown, this is changed to True. Then, inside the game loop I have added an event if x is pressed, kill the while loop. After testing, pressign x seems to do nothing. I do not see why this can be however as I have replicated use of the key event function that other stackoverflow answerers have used.

```
def refresh_window():
  if len(target_sprites) > 0:
   window.blit(bgr, (0,0))
  if len(target_sprites) == 0:
    window.blit(winner, (0,0))
    player_sprite.kill()
    game_over = True
  if target_1.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0))
    for item in target_sprites:
      item.kill()
    player_sprite.kill()
    game_over = True
```

```
while exec:
  current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exec = False

  key_press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if game_over == True:
    if key_press[K_x]:
      exec = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `game_over` in global namespace never becomes true.
`game_over` is a local variable in scope of `refresh_window`. If you want to set the same named variable `game_over` in global namespace, you have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt):

```py
def refresh_window():

    global game_over # <--- this is missing

    if len(target_sprites) > 0:
        window.blit(bgr, (0,0))
    if len(target_sprites) == 0:
        window.blit(winner, (0,0))
        player_sprite.kill()
        game_over = True
    if target_1.got_away == True:
        window.blit(loser, (0,0))
        for item in target_sprites:
            item.kill()
        player_sprite.kill()
        game_over = True
```

---

Another option would be to return `game_over` from  `refresh_window`:

```py
def refresh_window():
    game_over = False

    # [...]

    return game_over
```

```py
game_over = False 
while exec:
    # [...]

    key_press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if game_over == True:
        if key_press[K_x]:
            exec = False

    game_over = refresh_window()
```

Comment: @j_yerbe `game_over` is used twice, in the function. Is the while loop (`while exec:`) in a function, too? If yes, then you have to put `global game_over` in this function, too.

Comment: I am unable to declare it global in the while loop. Unfortunately globalising it inside the refresh window function did not have any effect either. I am using a website called repl.it, I dont know if you know it. Perhaps it does not work on repl.it but i cant see why it wouldnt

Comment: @j_yerbe Where do you call `refresh_window`? Do you call it in the loop?

Comment: Yes inside the game loop

Comment: @j_yerbe See the 2nd part of the answer.